# python TCPServer address already in use but I close the server and I use `allow_reuse_address`

Tags: python, tcp, port, bind

Here is my code to run the server:

```
class MyRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    #....

PORT = 8089

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), MyRequestHandler)
httpd.allow_reuse_address = True

print "Serving forever at port", PORT
try:
    httpd.serve_forever()
except:
    print "Closing the server."
    httpd.server_close()
    raise
```

Yet this is what happens:

```
^CClosing the server.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 118, in <module>
    self.send_error(400, "Unimplemented GET command: %s" % (self.path,))
  File "/home/claudiu/local/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 224, in serve_forever
    r, w, e = select.select([self], [], [], poll_interval)
KeyboardInterrupt
(.virtualenv)claudiu@xxx:~/xxx$ python server.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 122, in <module>
    httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), MyRequestHandler)
  File "/home/claudiu/local/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 402, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/home/claudiu/local/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 413, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Why? I close the server and set `allow_reuse_address` to True... Using python 2.6.8.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thanks to the other answers, I figured it out. `allow_reuse_address` should be on the class, not on the instance:

```
SocketServer.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), MyRequestHandler)
```

I'm still not sure why closing the socket didn't free it up for the next run of the server, though.

Comment: Is there a way to change the port and try again? I tried using `expcept OSError: port+=1 ...` but python does not catch the port error (ON python 3.7 it gives OSError Exception rather than socket.error exception)

Answer (score 15):

The `[Err 98] Address already in use` is due to the fact the socket was `.close()` but it's still waiting for enough time to pass to be sure the remote TCP received the acknowledgment of its connection termination request (see [TIME_WAIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)). By default you are not allowed to bind a socket if there a socket bound to that port but you can override that with `allow_reuse_address` (SO_REUSEADDR)

Although is possible to mutate `TCPServer.allow_reuse_addr` (as proposed in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15278302/90580)), I think is more clean to your own subclass of `TCPServer` where `allow_reuse_address` is set to `True`:

```
import SocketServer
import SimpleHTTPServer
import time

class MyRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET():
        time.sleep(60)
        self.request.sendall("I'm here!")

class ReuseAddrTCPServer(SocketServer.TCPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True

PORT = 8089

httpd = ReuseAddrTCPServer(("", PORT), MyRequestHandler)
httpd.daemon_threads = True


print "Serving forever at port", PORT
try:
    httpd.serve_forever()
except:
    print "Closing the server."
    httpd.server_close()
    raise
```

You can use definitely set `allow_reuse_address` on the instance itself (without messing with classes) but you need to use `TCPServer(..., bind_and_activate=False)`, otherwise the socket will be bound before you have a chance to change the `allow_reuse_address` setting. Then you need to manually call `.server_bind()` and `.server_activate()` before `serve_forever()`:

```
...
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), MyRequestHandler, bind_and_activate=False)
httpd.allow_reuse_address = True
httpd.daemon_threads = True
...
httpd.server_bind()
httpd.server_activate()
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because TCP [TIME_WAIT](http://dev.fyicenter.com/Interview-Questions/Socket-4/Explain_the_TIME_WAIT_state_.html).

[Somebody discovered this exact problem.](http://brokenbad.com/2012/01/address-reuse-in-pythons-socketserver/)

> However, if I try to stop and start the server again to test any modifications, I get a random “socket.error: [Errno 98] Address
>   already in use” error. This happens only if a client has already
>   connected to the server.
>
> Checking with netstat and ps, I found that although the process it
>   self is no longer running, the socket is still listening on the port
>   with status “TIME_WAIT”. Basically the OS  waits for a while to make
>   sure this connection has no remaining packets on the way.

Comment: Not a great citation. The *port* is still *present* in TIME_WAIT state. There is no socket, and no listening either.

Comment: I understand, but I wanted to know why my solutions (set `allow_reuse_address` and close the socket on shutdown) did not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have to set SO_REUSEADDRESS *before* you bind the socket. As you are creating and binding the socket all in one step and then setting it, it is already too late.

Comment: Ah so `allow_reuse_address` basically does nothing for the default `TCPServer` implementation? Also shouldn't closing the socket at the end of the program prevent this error?

Answer (score 0):

Address already in use
error happened when SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), MyRequestHandler), so you cannot catch below.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In "httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), MyRequestHandler)", will reset allow_reuse_address to False, so you set allow_reuse_address behind it is useless, regardless of closing the socket at the end of the program.