# Address already in use but nothing in netstat or lsof

Tags: python, linux, port, netstat, lsof

I try to start the Python SimpleHTTPServer on port 7054 :

```
$ sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 7054
...
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

So, I ran the following commands :

```
$ sudo netstat -ntpu | grep 7054
$ sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep 7054
```

But I have no results.

Comment: Looks like this one, man : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071512/socket-error-errno-48-address-already-in-use

Comment: The netstat and lsof commands should display any processes using the 7054 port. But nothing pop's out.

Comment: whats with sudo why not run using root. This could be the reason. not sure though

Comment: @daa. Why would sudo not work?

Comment: I think may be the netstat not working with sudo at all.

Comment: sudo is used to elevate the account if not logged in as root. If you do not elevate the account, you may not see all ports in use. [Reference](http://knowledgebase.pearsonschool.com/kmp/article/AA-02787/0/SMAKER%3A-How-to-use-netstat-Network-Statistics.html). Again I may be wrong

Comment: Netstat not working with sudo is highly uncertain BUT I tried (just in case) to run the commands directly as root) and the (no) results is the same. No processes use the port 7054 and yet I still have an "Address already in use" error.

Comment: sudo gives you root privileges without having to login as root.

Comment: I'm debugging a server program, and if I kill it without explicitly closing the server socket, I get this error for about 30 seconds. Seems that simply waiting a bit solves it.

Answer (score 13):

From the `netstat` manpage:

```
netstat   [address_family_options]   [--tcp|-t]   [--udp|-u]   [--raw|-w]   [--listening|-l]  [--all|-a]  [--numeric|-n]  [--numeric-hosts]  [--numeric-ports]
[--numeric-users] [--symbolic|-N] [--extend|-e[--extend|-e]] [--timers|-o] [--program|-p] [--verbose|-v] [--continuous|-c]
```

I use the following options:

```
sudo netstat -tanl | grep 7054
```

Which is `--numeric`, `--tcp`, `--all`, `--listening`

I think the minimal `netstat` options you need to show the pid of the process listening on a particular port are `-nlp`.

The `lsof` options you specify work for me. Using the example code at https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication#Receiving and `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 7054`:

```
$ netstat -nlp | grep 7054
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7054            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20458/python    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7054          0.0.0.0:*                           20498/python    
$ lsof -i -n -P | grep 7054
python    20458 michael    3u  IPv4 143736      0t0  TCP *:7054 (LISTEN)
python    20498 michael    3u  IPv4 173739      0t0  UDP *:7054
```

Extra credit: stick it in an alias:

```
listening() {
    netstat -nlp | grep $1
}
```

And use it:

```
$ listening 7054
```

Comment: Sorry but -tu is for TCP _or_ UDP not _and_ :  
  sudo netstat -lnptu | grep 63342  
  tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:63342  
This process is not listening on UDP but only TCP

Comment: Right. So then it's the missing `--listen` option that's the problem?

Comment: did you get the solution ?

Comment: For windows users: Try `netstat -anop tcp | frindstr 7054`. It gives you the PID in the last column and with `tasklist | findstr <pid>` you can get the process executable name for your PID to see who is allocating the port.

Answer (score 1):

An address can be in use, but not shown by `lsof`, `ss` or `netstat` once `bind` has been used on a `SOCK_STREAM` socket, but before the *named* socket has been set the `LISTEN` state.

This was found with a test performed using AlmaLinux 8.6 with a `4.18.0-372.19.1.el8_6.x86_64` Kernel.
The source for the test program is in [bind_local.c](https://github.com/Chester-Gillon/ibv_message_passing/blob/master/ibv_message_passing_c_project/source/bind_local/bind_local.c)

Start the test program, specifying an IPv6 link-local address and port number (10000) to bind to:

```
[mr_halfword@haswell-alma ibv_message_passing]$ ibv_message_passing_c_project/bin/debug/bind_local/bind_local  -6 fe80::207:43ff:fe15:2298%4 -p 10000 -l
fd 3 bound to fe80::207:43ff:fe15:2298 scope-id 4 port 10000
Press enter to listen on port
```

At the above port a `SOCK_STREAM` socket has been created, `bind` called and `getsockname` used to get the socket name which is displayed (i.e. the address the socket has been bound to).

The socket file-descriptor the test program has bound is shown as socket `398999`:

```
[mr_halfword@haswell-alma ~]$ ls -l /proc/`pgrep bind_local`/fd
total 0
lrwx------. 1 mr_halfword mr_halfword 64 Sep 10 17:08 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------. 1 mr_halfword mr_halfword 64 Sep 10 17:08 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------. 1 mr_halfword mr_halfword 64 Sep 10 17:08 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------. 1 mr_halfword mr_halfword 64 Sep 10 17:08 3 -> 'socket:[398999]'
```

In this state attempting to use `nc` to listen on port 10000 fails with *Address already in use*, but neither `lsof` not `ss` show the address:

```
[mr_halfword@haswell-alma ~]$ nc -l 10000
Ncat: bind to :::10000: Address already in use. QUITTING.
[mr_halfword@haswell-alma ~]$ sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep 10000
[mr_halfword@haswell-alma ~]$ sudo ss -nlp | grep 10000
[mr_halfword@haswell-alma ~]$
```

Cause the test program to call `listen` on the bound socket, by pressing return:

```
Press return to exit
```

Now that the bound socket is in the `LISTEN` state attempting to use `nc` to listen on port 10000 fails with *Address already in use*, but now `lsof` and `ss` are showing the address and which program is using the address:

```
[mr_halfword@haswell-alma ~]$ sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep 10000
bind_loca 16929 mr_halfword    3u  IPv6 398999      0t0  TCP [fe80::207:43ff:fe15:2298]:10000 (LISTEN)
[mr_halfword@haswell-alma ~]$ sudo ss -nlp | grep 10000
tcp   LISTEN 0      1                       [fe80::207:43ff:fe15:2298]%enp1s0f4d1:10000               [::]:*     users:(("bind_local",pid=16929,fd=3))
```

I haven't yet tried looking at the Linux Kernel source code to determine if a `SOCK_STREAM` socket which has been bound to an address by being *named*, but left in that state, has any user space method which can locate the program using the address.

The reason the above was investigating how the `iwpmd` *iWARP Port Mapper Daemon* was claiming TCP ports, for which was unable to find a way to list the claimed TCP ports.

Comment: For a ``SOCK_DGRAM`` socket the issue doesn't apply, in that once have called ``bind`` the address is shown by ``lsof``, ``ss`` and ``netstat``.