# netstat local address, port represented by string

Tags: port, netstat

What ports are represented by the strings `irdmi`, `availant-mgr`, etc...?

In general, how do I figure this out? Is it assigned in some file somewhere?

```
netstat -lp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:irdmi                     *:*                         LISTEN      4648/python
tcp        0      0 *:availant-mgr              *:*                         LISTEN      1777/sshd
tcp        0      0 *:shell                     *:*                         LISTEN      1732/xinetd
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*                         LISTEN      1698/sshd
```

Comment: The names come from `/etc/protocols`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the -n flag to show numerical addresses and ports.

`netstat -an`

Answer (score -1):

If you run `netstat -a` it should list the actual port numbers you are listening on.

Typical protocol ports can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

e.g. irdmi is typically 8000, SSH is 22.