# OsError 10048 Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

I have been working on a program that gets all the answers to the questions provided by an API and checks if they are correct. Since there are thousands of questions I have implemented multithreading to collect the answers. However, even though the program works fine with one thread, every time I set the number of workers to a number greater than one I get the following error during at a random point  during the execution of the for loop:

```
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

The error usually ocurrs when about 10%-20% of the answers have been retrieved.

```
def data_tests(db_env, data_env, db_company, data_company, lang):


    def get_answers_encapsulated(input_question):
          return data.get_answers(
          env=data_env,
          company=data_company,
          question=input_question["question"],
          lang=lang,
        )


    questions = data.read_questions_answers(env=db_env, company=db_company)


    widgets = [
       "* Getting answers: ",
       Percentage(),
       " ",
       Bar(),
       " ",
       ETA(),
       " ",
       AdaptiveETA(),
       ]
   pbar = ProgressBar(widgets=widgets, maxval=len(questions))
   pbar_progress = 0
   pbar.start()

   with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
      for question, result in zip(
        questions, 
        executor.map(get_answers_encapsulated, questions.values())
       ):
           questions[question]["answers"] = result
           pbar_progress += 1
           pbar.update(pbar_progress)
       pbar.finish()
    ....
```

Here is the get answers function:

```
def get_answers(env: str, company: int, question: str, lang: str) -> List:

    data_url = f"http://{BASE_URL[env]}/companies/{company}/search/?lang_code={lang}&search_type=default"
    data_body = {"question": question}

    with requests.Session() as s:
        response = s.post(data_url, json=data_body)

        if (
            response.status_code == 400
            or response.status_code == 404
            or "results" not in response.json().keys()
            or len(response.json()["results"]) == 0
        ):
            return []
        else:
            answers = []
            for result in response.json()["results"]:

                q_id = result["_source"]["questionId"]
                answer = result["_source"]["answer"]
                score = result["_score"]

                answers.append({"score": score, "q_id": q_id, "answer": answer})

            return answers
```

Here is the output on the logs of the server when the error ocurrs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2021 00:45:54] "POST /companies/175/search/?lang_code=es&search_type=default HTTP/1.1" 200 -
HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url: /_alias/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001AD13FF7630>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted',))
HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url: /zapidx_3_es/_analyze (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001AD1619CBA8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted',))
HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url: /_alias/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001AD15914470>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted',))
HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url: /_alias/zap_es (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001AD1591DDA0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted',))
```

I would like to know if there is any way to prevent this from happening. If there is no way, how can I manage the exception to get all the answers?

EDIT: Here's the full trace of error.

```
* Getting answers:  18% |####                   | ETA:   0:04:21 ETA:   0:04:43Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 234, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\http\client.py", line 1257, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\http\client.py", line 1303, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\http\client.py", line 1252, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\http\client.py", line 1012, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\http\client.py", line 952, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 200, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 181, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000026B8FD75610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8004): Max retries exceeded with url: /companies/175/search/?lang_code=es&search_type=default (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000026B8FD75610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Manue\Documents\Zapiens\OldBackend\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\data-tests.py", line 118, in <module>
    data_tests()
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Manue\Documents\Zapiens\OldBackend\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\data-tests.py", line 89, in data_tests
    for question, result in zip(
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 608, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 438, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 390, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 52, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Manue\Documents\Zapiens\OldBackend\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\data-tests.py", line 60, in get_answers_encapsulated
    return data.get_answers(
  File "C:\Users\Manue\Documents\Zapiens\OldBackend\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\modules\data.py", line 71, in get_answers
    response = s.post(data_url, json=data_body)
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 590, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Manue\miniconda3\envs\zapiens-data-sv-search-data-tests\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8004): Max retries exceeded with url: /companies/175/search/?lang_code=es&search_type=default (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000026B8FD75610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace of the error

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Yes, I have edited the OP with the trace of error

Comment: @Xitiz I have tried to use try  - except in the get_answers_encapsulated() function, however, after the exception raises the following requests fail and i only get the first 10-20% correctly (the ones processed before the exception happens)

Comment: You are probably leaking sockets somewhere. Make sure they are closed via all possible execution paths.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767905/) helps you? Since you're sending requests to localhost you can change code of server.