# Q: OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, visual-studio-code

I am new to python socket programming and I need a help.

I am trying to make an app for people to chat.

This Exception is too long. I only know that it is OSE Error. Please help me.

There is my problem -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Dell\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.6.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\Dell\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.6.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 444, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Dell\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.6.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 285, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))      
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 262, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 95, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Dell\Documents\calc\input_messagers\server.py", line 12, in <module>
    server.bind((HOST, PORT))
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

I don't know what to do. Can you help me?

Please answer me as fast as you can.

There is my code -

## server.py

```
import socket
import threading

HOST = '192.168.1.106'
PORT = 5050

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))

server.listen()

clients = []
nicknames = []

def broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message)

def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024)
            print(f"{nicknames[clients.index(client)]}")
            broadcast(message)
        except:
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            nickname = nicknames[index]
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            break

def receive():
    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        print(f"Connected with {str(address)}")

        client.send("NICK".encode('utf-8'))
        nickname = client.recv(1024)

        nicknames.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)

        print(f"Nickname of the cilent is {nickname}")
        broadcast(f"{nickname} connected to the server!\n".encode('utf-8'))
        client.send("Connected to the server".encode('utf-8'))

        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()

print("Server running...")
receive()
```

## client.py

```
import socket
import threading
import tkinter
from tkinter import simpledialog

from server import receive


HOST = '192.168.1.106'
PORT = 5050

class Client:
    def __init(self, host, port):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect()

        msg = tkinter.Tk()
        msg.withdraw()

        self.nickname = simpledialog.askstring("Nickname", "Please choose a nickname", parent=msg)

        self.gui_done = False

        self.running = True

        gui_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.gui_loop)
        receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)

        gui_thread.start()
        receive_thread.start()

    def gui_loop(self):
        self.win = tkinter.Tk()
        self.win.configure(bg="lightgray")

        self.chat_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="Chat: ", bg="lightgray")
        self.chat_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.chat_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.text_area = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.win)
        self.text_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)
        self.text_area.config(state='disabled')

        self.msg_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="Chat: ", bg="lightgray")
        self.msg_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.msg_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.input_area = tkinter.Text(self.win, height=3)
        self.input_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.send_button = tkinter.Button(self.win, text="Send", command=self.write)
        self.send_button.config(font=('Aerial', 12))

        self.gui_cone = True

        self.win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.stop)

        self.win.mainloop()

    def write(self):
        message = f"{self.nickname}: {self.input_area.get('1.0','end')}"
        self.sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
        self.input_area.delete('1.0', 'end')

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        self.win.destroy()
        self.sock.close()
        exit(0)

    def receive(self):
        while self.running:
            try:
                message = self.sock.recv(1024)
                if message == 'NICK':
                    self.sock.send(self.nickname.encode('utf-8'))
                else:
                    if self.gui_done:
                        self.text_area.config(state='normal')
                        self.text_area.insert('end', message)
                        self.text_area.yview('end')
                        self.text_area.config(state='disabled')
            except ConnectionAbortedError:
                break
            except:
                print("Error")
                self.sock.close()
                break

client = Client(HOST, PORT)
```

Please answer me if you know the solution.

Thanks

Comment: Can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767905/errno-10048-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocol-network-address-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means all available ports on the machine are being exhausted.
Try changing your port number for both client and server