# How can i change a service running on one port number, now i want to run another service on same old port number

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, port

I am using a deployment yaml file ex:nginx which i am using port 30080.
Now i wrote another deployment yaml file but i want to use port number 30080.

> The Service "web" is invalid: spec.ports[0].nodePort: Invalid value: 30080: >provided port is already allocated

How can i use the port number 30080 for my new deployment web.yaml file.
1)Deleted the nginx pod running.
2)Deleted nginx deployment running.

> But how can i free up the port number 30080.

i checked the port number:

> > > sudo iptables-save | grep 30080

```
-A KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/nginx-service: has no endpoints" -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -m tcp --dport 30080 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-
port-unreachable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i deleted deployment and pod. But i forgot that service is running after deleting nginx service i am able to reuse the port number 30080 for other deployment.

[socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071512/socket-error-errno-48-address-already-in-use)

this question also helped me but it points to killing that process, here the process running is kube-proxy.

> sudo lsof -i:30080
>
> COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF
> NODE NAME kube-prox 3320 root    8u  IPv6  40388      0t0  TCP *:30080
> (LISTEN)

which i cant delete.It might create issue deleting kube-prox

Please let me know if this was the right approach or not.