# TCP Server code in python, [Errno 48] Address already in use

Tags: python, tcpserver

I am trying to write a code in python so that a client will send requests to the server to reverse strings (taken as a command line input) over the network using sockets. I tried to execute the below Server code and it gave me [Errno 48] Address already in use.
I`d appreciate helping me to solve this error.

Here is the code:

```
import socket
serverPort = 12000
serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print("Ther server is ready to receive the connection...")
while True:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
    ReverseSentence = sentence[::-1]
    connectionSocket.send(ReverseSentence.encode()) 
    connectionSocket.close()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071512/socket-error-errno-48-address-already-in-use

Comment: There's another process listening on port 12000 already. Another instance of your program?

Comment: Is there a way I can find out whether this port is already in use?