# Displaying a temporary html file with webbrowser in Python

Tags: python, temporary-files

Really simple, I want to create a temporary html page that I display with the usual webbrowser.

Why does the following code produce an empty page?

```
import tempfile 
import webbrowser 
import time

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('r+', suffix = '.html') as f:
    f.write('<html><body><h1>Test</h1></body></html>') 
    webbrowser.open('file://' + f.name) 
    time.sleep(1) # to prevent the file from dying before displayed
```

Comment: You need to close or flush the file before the changes are written to disk.

Comment: @Ken Ah... right! I see, `f.flush()` did it.

Comment: Is there a better way to make sure webbrowser is able to load the page before it dies?

Comment: I don't believe so. `webbrowser.open` seems to return a boolean indicating if it successfully instructed the browser to open the file, I don't know of a way to see if the browser has actually opened the file.

Answer (score 5):

Because your file doesn't exist on the disk and sits entirely in memory. That's why the browser starts but opens nothing since no code has been provided.

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tempfile 
import webbrowser 

tmp=tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
path=tmp.name+'.html'

f=open(path, 'w')
f.write("<html><body><h1>Test</h1></body></html>")
f.close()
webbrowser.open('file://' + path)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the file will not be deleted. If you try to delete it right after `webbrowser.open()`, it will delete it before it has been fully loaded.

Comment: Usually files in /tmp are deleted automatically  but you mentioned sleep that provided a delay. It works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Tested on Python 3.4.

```
import subprocess
import webbrowser
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer


PORT = 7000
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
SERVER_ADDRESS = '{host}:{port}'.format(host=HOST, port=PORT)
FULL_SERVER_ADDRESS = 'http://' + SERVER_ADDRESS


def TemproraryHttpServer(page_content_type, raw_data):
    """
    A simpe, temprorary http web server on the pure Python 3.
    It has features for processing pages with a XML or HTML content.
    """

    class HTTPServerRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
        """
        An handler of request for the server, hosting XML-pages.
        """

        def do_GET(self):
            """Handle GET requests"""

            # response from page
            self.send_response(200)

            # set up headers for pages
            content_type = 'text/{0}'.format(page_content_type)
            self.send_header('Content-type', content_type)
            self.end_headers()

            # writing data on a page
            self.wfile.write(bytes(raw_data, encoding='utf'))

            return

    if page_content_type not in ['html', 'xml']:
        raise ValueError('This server can serve only HTML or XML pages.')

    page_content_type = page_content_type

    # kill a process, hosted on a localhost:PORT
    subprocess.call(['fuser', '-k', '{0}/tcp'.format(PORT)])

    # Started creating a temprorary http server.
    httpd = HTTPServer((HOST, PORT), HTTPServerRequestHandler)

    # run a temprorary http server
    httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    def run_xml_server():

        xml_data = """
        <note>
        <to>Tove</to>
        <from>Jani</from>
        <heading>Reminder</heading>
        <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
        </note>
        """

        # open in a browser URL and see a result
        webbrowser.open(FULL_SERVER_ADDRESS)

        # run server
        TemproraryHttpServer('xml', xml_data)

    def run_html_server():

        html_data = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
        </body>
        </html>
        """

        # open in a browser URL and see a result
        webbrowser.open(FULL_SERVER_ADDRESS)

        # run server
        TemproraryHttpServer('html', html_data)

    # choice needed server:

    # run_xml_server()
    # run_html_server()
```

Comment: This thing saved me a lot of hassle, although I rewrote it a bit. One useful addition might be to replace `subprocess` with `kill` to `HTTPServer.allow_reuse_address=True`. And `serve_forever` can be wrapped into try-except, so that the user can exit to the interactive shell with a `sigterm`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260558/python-tcpserver-address-already-in-use-but-i-close-the-server-and-i-use-allow

Answer (score 2):

Just change the file's current position.

```
import tempfile 
import webbrowser 
import time

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('r+', suffix = '.html') as f:
    f.write('<html><body><h1>Test</h1></body></html>') 
    webbrowser.open('file://' + f.name) 
    f.seek(0)
    time.sleep(1) # to prevent the file from dying before displayed
```

Comment: What does f.seek(0) do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is an edition to the previews one and continuation of the discussion with the OP. It shows time.sleep() after webbrowser.open(). I don't think it's actually needed because the /tmp directory is emptied automatically on a regular bases by the OS but the OP commented that if he deletes the temp file via Python it is deleted before it gets fully loaded by the browser. Most likely it happens because the "browser" process is detached from this scrip which is its parent and Python doesn't wait for the process completion before executing the next statement. I though it would be clear for everyone without explanation but obviously you, guys, don't read comments.

```
import os, time

#      ...

webbrowser.open('file://' + path)
time.sleep(1)

if os.path.exists(path):
    os.remove(path)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: Are you trying to edit your other answer? This looks like it's meant to be an addition to it?

Comment: This site is not set up like a normal forum with posts that go in time order. Your code here would probably be easier to understand if edited into your other answer as an additional section of it.